# Map a multimap to columns of dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, rdd

Simply, I want to convert a multimap like this:

```
val input = Map("rownum"-> List("1", "2", "3") ,  "plant"-> List( "Melfi", "Pomigliano", "Torino" ), "tipo"-> List("gomme", "telaio")).toArray
```

in the following Spark dataframe:

```
+-------+--------------+-------+
|rownum |   plant      | tipo  |
+------ +--------------+-------+
| 1     |   Melfi      | gomme |
| 2     |   Pomigliano | telaio|
| 3     |   Torino     | null  |
+-------+--------------+-------+
```

replacing missing values with "null" values. My issue is apply a map function to the RDD:

```
val inputRdd = sc.parallelize(input)
inputRdd.map(..).toDF()
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

Comment: How to you know that the missing "tipo" value is that of `rownum 3` ? It could come from anywhere, unless there is a reason for you to know that missing values can only come from "truncated" lists.

Comment: Because the column's name are XML tags extract in order. So imagine you have the following xml: <row> <rownum> 1</rownum> <plant> Melfi</plant> <tipo>gomme</tipo></row> <row> <rownum> 2</rownum> <plant> Pomigliano</plant> <tipo>telaio</tipo></row> <row> <rownum> 3</rownum> <plant> Torino</plant></row>  . As you can see plant Torino hano "tipo", so I want replace that missing value with "null".

Comment: thanks for the reply. You may edit your question to add this relevant information, this is more readable for future readers.

Comment: the XML tells me that rownum 3 has no "typo", but the multimap does not allow me to draw this conclusion. Take the same XML, but remove the tipo from rownum 2 and put it in rownum 3, you'll get the same multimap. Your XML to Map seems to destroy this crucial information of where the nulls come from.

Answer (score 0):

Although, see my comments, I'm really not sure the multimap format is well suited to your problem (did you have a look at [Spark XML parsing modules](https://github.com/databricks/spark-xml) ?)

### The pivot table solution

The idea is to flatten you input table into a `(elementPosition, columnName, columnValue)` format :

```
// The max size of the multimap lists
val numberOfRows = input.map(_._2.size).max
// For each index in the list, emit a tuple of (index, multimap key, multimap value at index)
val flatRows = (0 until numberOfRows).flatMap(rowIdx => input.map({ case (colName, allColValues) => (rowIdx, colName, if(allColValues.size > rowIdx) allColValues(rowIdx) else null)}))
// Probably faster at runtime to write it this way (less iterations) : 
// val flatRows = input.flatMap({ case (colName, existingValues) => (0 until numberOfRows).zipAll(existingValues, null, null).map(t => (t._1.asInstanceOf[Int], colName, t._2)) })
// To dataframe
val flatDF = sc.parallelize(flatRows).toDF("elementIndex", "colName", "colValue")
flatDF.show
```

Will output :

```
+------------+-------+----------+
|elementIndex|colName|  colValue|
+------------+-------+----------+
|           0| rownum|         1|
|           0|  plant|     Melfi|
|           0|   tipo|     gomme|
|           1| rownum|         2|
|           1|  plant|Pomigliano|
|           1|   tipo|    telaio|
|           2| rownum|         3|
|           2|  plant|    Torino|
|           2|   tipo|      null|
+------------+-------+----------+
```

Now this is a pivot table problem :

```
flatDF.groupBy("elementIndex").pivot("colName").agg(expr("first(colValue)")).drop("elementIndex").show
+----------+------+------+
|     plant|rownum|  tipo|
+----------+------+------+
|Pomigliano|     2|telaio|
|    Torino|     3|  null|
|     Melfi|     1| gomme|
+----------+------+------+
```

This might not be the best looking solution, but it is fully scalable to any number of columns.